# Apache camel CamelSftpSourceConnector split file

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm reading `Apache Camel` documentation, but I cannot find any information about my use case.

I have a SFTP server which has very big files, so what I would like to do is, using `CamelSftpSourceConnector` I would like to use my own `converter` to split that file in small pieces and send each of them to Kafka.

Do you know if that's something doable with the library?

Regards.

Comment: In general Camel allows to define [custom converters](https://camel.apache.org/manual/type-converter.html) that map some inbound type to an outbound type. Whether the this can be used for splitting depends on  the file and type at hand. I.e. archives usually need to be fully downloaded before their contents can be extracted and feed into the splitter while for XML contents the tokens can easily be used in a stream while loading the bytes of that XML file

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documentation. In our case is totally fine fully download the whole file from the FTP server, but we need to split this file in small events to be send to Kafka. We cannot send an event to Kafka of 500mb :).  Any idea where to find how to tell CamelSftpSourceConnector  to use a specific converter, and how to get an input T and return a List<T> to be sent to Kafka?

Comment: [In this camel + kafka + sftp connector example](https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector-examples/blob/a6a469b331e4f075fe24eee21c061701284074a1/sftp/sftp-source/README.adoc) they use a custom transformer to map the file to Kafka records. Not sure if you can specify the types in a way to return a list of Kafka records. As I have not used Camel with Kafka before I unfortunately can't give more detailed examples or explanations. You might consult the Camel devs directly via Zulip i.e. They usually respond rather quickly